# Concert a Flex object to a Json String?

Tags: json, apache-flex

How do you convert a Flex object to a JSon string? For example:

```
var a:Array = new Array();
var object:Object = {
    id:1,  processed:false 
};
a.push(object);
```

I want "a" to be a json string. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Take this script: https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js

And call:

```
var myJsonString = JSON.stringify(yourArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can get away with using Flash Player 11 or greater you can use:
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/JSON.html

If not you can use the JSON class from as3corelib:
https://github.com/mikechambers/as3corelib/